# How set different rowsizes in tabular?

Tags: tables, tabularx

> How can I set a certain row height in certain places and how can I make center alignment in a cell, both horizontally and vertically

```
I need this:
```

[image: I need this]

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Time & \textbf{Thursday 04} & \textbf{Friday 05} & \textbf{Saturday 06}\\
    \hline
    09:30 - 10:20 & & V.Voronov & Yu. Tchuvil'sky \\
    \hline
    10:20 - 11:10 & & N.Antonenko & G.Adamian \\
    \hline\hline
    11:10 - 11:30 & \textbf{Opening} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Break}}\\
    \hline\hline
    11:30 - 12:20 & Yu. Oganessian & N. Van Giai & A. Diaz-Torres\\
    \hline
    12:20 - 13:10 & Yu. Oganessian & N. Van Giai & V.Sargsyan \\
    \hline\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{13:10 - 15:00 Lunch}}\\
    \hline\hline
    15:00 - 15:35 & N. Antonenko & Yu. Tchuvil'sky & V. Dobrev \\
    \hline
    15:35 - 16:10 & V. Sargsyan & A. Diaz-Torres & R. Poghossian \\
    \hline
    16:10 - 16:45 & G. Adamian & E. Kolganova & R.Poghossian \\
    \hline\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{16:45 - 17:10 Break}}\\
    \hline\hline
    17:10 - 18:00 & A. Gozdz & A. Gusev & Lu Guo \\
    \hline
    18:00 - 18:30 & Lu Guo & A.Gusev & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

```
But i have this
```

[image: But i have this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I managed to find the best solution for myself with *stackengine*

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    Time & \textbf{Thursday 04} & \textbf{Friday 05} & \textbf{Saturday 06}\\
    \hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    09:30 - 10:20 & & V. Voronov & Yu. Tchuvil'sky \\
    \hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    10:20 - 11:10 & & N. Antonenko & G. Adamian \\
    \hline\hline\xrowht[()]{5pt}
    11:10 - 11:30 & \textbf{Opening} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\large\textbf{Break}}\\
    \hline\hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    11:30 - 12:20 & Yu. Oganessian & N. Van Giai & A. Diaz-Torres\\
    \hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    12:20 - 13:10 & Yu. Oganessian & N. Van Giai & V. Sargsyan \\
    \hline\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large\textbf{13:10 - 15:00 Lunch}}\xrowht[()]{5pt}\\
    \hline\hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    15:00 - 15:35 & N. Antonenko & Yu. Tchuvil'sky & V. Dobrev \\
    \hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    15:35 - 16:10 & V. Sargsyan & A. Diaz-Torres & R. Poghossian \\
    \hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    16:10 - 16:45 & G. Adamian & E. Kolganova & R.Poghossian \\
    \hline\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large\textbf{16:45 - 17:10 Break}}\xrowht[()]{5pt}\\
    \hline\hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    17:10 - 18:00 & A. Gozdz & A. Gusev & Lu Guo \\
    \hline\xrowht[()]{35pt}
    18:00 - 18:30 & Lu Guo & A.Gusev & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed height rows are not a trivial matter in latex. I propose a solution based on `minipage` environment. I show you a general example that you can use whenever you want

A new column type `v{width}{height}` is defined. The vertical alignment is set by the second [c] option of the `minipage` environment. The horizontal alignment is set by the `\centering` declaration inside him. The rest of the syntax is the usual one of the `array` package.

note. If the code don't compile, you will need the last version of `array` package. A quick solution is load `tabularx`. Add to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcolumntype{v}[2]{%
    >{\begin{minipage}[c][#2][c]{#1}\centering\arraybackslash}c<{\end{minipage}}%
    }

\begin{document}

\def\text{This text is a example}

\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{v{3cm}{2cm}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Title row} \\
\hline
\text & \text & \text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\

\end{document}
```